# Get specific column from the last inserted row with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, sql-insert

I have a MySQL table `users`, with auto-increment `userid` column. After I `INSERT` a new user row with PDO, is there a way to get its userid?

I know about `PDO::lastInsertId` but I'm not sure if this gives the correct value. According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), it gives the "ID of the row".

More generally, can I get a specific column from the last inserted row, without creating a new query?

Comment: No, you get the ID of the last inserted row. To get a specific column, you know it due to insert, or query it by the lastInsertId.

Comment: If userid is the primary key of that table I believe last_inserted_id returns the last primary key it inserts into the table.

Comment: In MySQL if `userid` is the only auto-incremented value then `lastInsertId` is pretty reliable

Comment: didn't you just inserted that value?

Comment: @user663976 I believed it too, but wanted to confirm, as it's not clear from the doc.

Comment: @user3187724 what you could do is to insert a new row manually with a large id into mysql, and run your code. If the last id that comes back is incremented after that large id, then you can be sure that it is right.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Fair point. I don't actually need that, so didn't think it through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a MySQL table users, with auto-increment userid column. After I INSERT a new user row with PDO, is there a way to get its userid?

That's exactly what `lastInsertId` does: it gives you the value of the auto-incremented column for the last insert. Note, however, that if your query inserted multiple rows at once, the id of the *last inserted row* is returned. This is described [in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).

> More generally, can I get a specific column from the last inserted row, without creating a new query?

No. Some databases support the `returning` clause, that lets an `insert` query return columns from the inserted row(s), but not MySQL. So you would indeed need to run a `select` query after the `insert`, using the last insert id as a filter. One might argue that, if you just performed an `insert`, you supposedly know which values were inserted (or you can infer the default value for columns whose values you did not supply).